# Python multiprocessing - starmap_async does not work where starmap does?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

This `starmap` example program works as intended:

```
import multiprocessing

def main():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(10)
    params = [ (2, 2), (4, 4), (6, 6) ]
    pool.starmap(printSum, params)
# end function

def printSum(num1, num2):
    print('in printSum')
    mySum = num1 + num2
    print('num1 = ' + str(num1) + ', num2 = ' + str(num2) + ', sum = ' + str(mySum))
# end function

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

output:

```
in printSum
num1 = 2, num2 = 2, sum = 4
in printSum
num1 = 4, num2 = 4, sum = 8
in printSum
num1 = 6, num2 = 6, sum = 12
```

But if I change the `starmap` line to `starmap_async` like so:

```
pool.starmap_async(printSum, params)
```

and keep everything else the same I get no output at all !?!?  From reading the docs
https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map_async
I'm unable to determine a reason for this.  I've used starmap_async successfully in other situations.  What am I missing here ??

--- Edit ---

I found that if in the above working program I change the line

```
pool.starmap(printSum, params)
```

to the following two lines:

```
result = pool.starmap_async(printSum, params)
result.get()
```

Then I get the expected result, so I suppose this at least solves the problem.  But can somebody please explain why `.get()` is not necessary for the non-`async` version of `map` / `starmap` but `.get()` is necessary for the `async` versions ??  The really confusing thing is that for the `async` versions in some cases `.get()` is necessary (as above) but in other cases with the `async` version `.get()` is not necessary and I'm unable to determine how/why/when `.get()` is necessary other than through experimentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't await the result from the [future](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult) you get with calling `.starmap_async()`, or do anything else what would prevent the `MainProcess` from exiting right after scheduling the job.

`pool.starmap_async(printSum, params).wait()` would do it, but it's pointless here. The async-variants make only sense if you need the calling thread unblocked to do something else in the meantime.

Comment: But if I add wait(), doesn't that prevent execution from continuing and doing other stuff, which I'm under the impression is the whole point of having the _async version available vs the non-asynch version.  I've found if I do pool.starmap_async(printSum, params).get() that seems to solve it, but I still don't understand what is going on completely.  I just updated my question for this.

Comment: @cdahms Your code doesn't show you doing something else or returning a result. If you need the result you would use `.get()`. They don't make a difference otherwise here. Run it multiple times, it depends on your OS how fast and when something will execute.